# R: multiply two arrays

Tags: r

I have a 2d array

`P = array(1,dim = c(2,2))`

and I want to multiply it with

`x = c(1,1)`

I am interested in the quantity matrix multiplication of P with x transpose.

I can't use `P*x` since R assumes that x is of dimension 1x2. Whats the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `%*%` what you're after?

Comment: does %*% work for multiplying two arrays? The problem is that Im working with arrays, and dont want to convert array to matrices and viceversa.

Comment: Consult `help("%*%")` for details

Comment: A matrix is an array. For example, `is.array(matrix(0,2,2))` returns TRUE.

Comment: @lmo then whats the difference between the two (with regards to the numeric variables)? Which one do people prefer usually (which one is more commonly used)?

Comment: Matrices are 2 dimensional arrays, so the distinction is pretty much arbitrary. You can check this with `is.matrix(array(1,dim = c(2,2)))`, which returns TRUE. Matrices tend to be more commonly used in R, but arrays can be pretty useful to work with in a multidimensional setting.